# Balanced vs. totally balanced cooperative games

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I would like to understand what [here](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~raumann/pdf/game%20theory.pdf) on the page 89 is the difference of totally balanced game vs. balanced one. More precisely, I would like to see a game which is balanced but not totally balanced. Where $U$ ranges through for totally balanced game? Also, is this guess correct: game is balanced iff it has a nonempty core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition and notation of the above reference is not quite understandable on a quick glance, so I restate here the definitions and major statements of these concepts.

We say that a game $v \in \mathcal{G}^{n}$ is balanced if for every balanced collection $\mathcal{B}$ with weights $\{w_{S}\}_{S \in \mathcal{B}}$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
 \label{eq:bal_propA}
  \sum_{S \in \mathcal{B}}\,w_{S}\,v(S) \le v(N). 
\end{equation}
A game $v \in \mathcal{G}^{n}$ is called to be totally balanced if all subgames $\langle\,S,v_{S}\,\rangle, \emptyset \neq S \subseteq N$ are balanced. Notice that a subgame $\langle\,S,v_{S}\,\rangle$ is specified by $v_{S}(T)=v(T)$ for all $T \subseteq S$. Bondareva (1963) and Shapley (1967) proved independently from one another that a game $v \in \mathcal{G}^{n}$ is balanced iff the core of the game is non-empty, that is, $\mathcal{C}(N,v) \neq \emptyset$. Implying that a game is totally balanced iff any subgame has a non-empty core.

The class of market and flow games are totally balanced games. Moreover, the class of wedge games are totally balanced too, which are defined by

$v=\bigwedge\{{\boldsymbol\lambda}^{\,1},\ldots,{\boldsymbol\lambda}^{\,r}\}$,

whereas the ${\boldsymbol\lambda}^{\,k}$'s are assignment vectors. Hence, games that do not belong to these classes of games and have a non-empty core cannot be expected to be totally balanced.

Comment: What do you mean by this notation: $v=\bigwedge\{{\boldsymbol\lambda}^{\,1},\ldots,{\boldsymbol\lambda}^{\,r}\}$ ? Thank you for your helpful answer.

Comment: @user122424 The wedge game definition is a more succinctly definition of $v(S) := \min\{\lambda^{\,1}(S),\ldots,\lambda^{\,r}(S) \}$ for all $S \subseteq N$.

Comment: Could you please specify the (resources of) definitions for market and flow games ?

Comment: @user122424 have a look in the book Game Theory by M. Maschler, E. Solan, and S. Zamir, Cambridge University Press (2013).